# Is this face inside or outside the Hamilton cycle?

Tags: graph-theory

Assume a planar graph with a Hamilton cycle (depicted in green).

$\hskip2in$[image]

There are two possiblities for the displayed vertices to show up al0ng the Hamilton cycle:

1. $\dots ef\dots xy\dots$
2. $\dots ef\dots yx\dots$

What does it mean for the square $F$, 
if it's $xy$ or $yx$? Does this mean that it's inside or outside the
Hamilton cycle? Does [Grinberg's Theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grinberg%27s_theorem) play a role here?

Comment: The question arose, while thinking about [this](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/261069/19341) one...

Comment: Intuitively ..ef..xy.. should be impossible, because F cannot both be in the component of the plane that lies to the left of the cycle and the component that lies to the right.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Expanding the comment-answer by Henning Makholm: case 1 is impossible. A Hamilton cycle in a planar graph is a simple closed curve $\Gamma$ (a Jordan curve). By [the Jordan curve theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jordan_curve_theorem)   $\Gamma$ divides the plane into two regions: bounded $B$ and unbounded $U$. The region $B$ is homeomorphic to a disk by [the Schoenflies theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schoenflies_problem). The orientation of $B$ induces positive orientation of its boundary $\Gamma$, formalizing the intuitive notion of "$B$ stays to the left of its boundary". Since the square $F$ is either in $B$ or in the complement of $B$, case 1 is inconsistent with such orientation.

Comment: Thanks for setteling the case. Would be glad if you could have a look at the linked one...